# ojAlgo - Optimization issue with contiguous block logic?

Tags: kotlin, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, ojalgo

I am using ojAlgo to work through a classroom scheduling problem I'm doing as an exercise. The source code can be found here on GitHub in the `kotlin_solution` folder:

https://github.com/thomasnield/optimized-scheduling-demo

Everything was going fine until I started to implement contiguous block logic [which I've described over on Math Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583825/integer-programming-making-schedule-blocks-contiguous). Bascially, if a class session requires 4 blocks then those 4 blocks need to be together.

For some reason, this modeling logic screeches to a halt when I implement the contiguous logic [in this part of the code](https://github.com/thomasnield/optimized-scheduling-demo/blob/master/kotlin_solution/src/main/kotlin/ScheduleEntities.kt#L125-L148). It is churning infinitely.

Here is the Kotlin code in it's entirety:

```
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.ExpressionsBasedModel
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.Variable
import java.time.DayOfWeek
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

// declare model
val model = ExpressionsBasedModel()

val funcId = AtomicInteger(0)
val variableId = AtomicInteger(0)
fun variable() = Variable(variableId.incrementAndGet().toString().let { "Variable$it" }).apply(model::addVariable)
fun addExpression() = funcId.incrementAndGet().let { "Func$it"}.let { model.addExpression(it) }




// Any Monday through Friday date range will work
val operatingDates = LocalDate.of(2017,10,16)..LocalDate.of(2017,10,20)
val operatingDay = LocalTime.of(8,0)..LocalTime.of(17,0)


val breaks = listOf<ClosedRange<LocalTime>>(
        //LocalTime.of(11,30)..LocalTime.of(13,0)
)


// classes
val scheduledClasses = listOf(
        ScheduledClass(id=1, name="Psych 101", hoursLength=1.0, repetitions=2),
        ScheduledClass(id=2, name="English 101", hoursLength=1.5, repetitions=3),
        ScheduledClass(id=3, name="Math 300", hoursLength=1.5, repetitions=2),
        ScheduledClass(id=4, name="Psych 300", hoursLength=3.0, repetitions=1),
        ScheduledClass(id=5, name="Calculus I", hoursLength=2.0, repetitions=2),
        ScheduledClass(id=6, name="Linear Algebra I", hoursLength=2.0, repetitions=3),
        ScheduledClass(id=7, name="Sociology 101", hoursLength=1.0, repetitions=2),
        ScheduledClass(id=8, name="Biology 101", hoursLength=1.0, repetitions=2)
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {


    println("Job started at ${LocalTime.now()}")

    applyConstraints()

    println(model.minimise())

    Session.all.forEach {
        println("${it.name}-${it.repetitionIndex}: ${it.start.dayOfWeek} ${it.start.toLocalTime()}-${it.end.toLocalTime()}")
    }

    println("Job ended at ${LocalTime.now()}")

}



data class Block(val dateTimeRange: ClosedRange<LocalDateTime>) {

    val timeRange = dateTimeRange.let { it.start.toLocalTime()..it.endInclusive.toLocalTime() }

    fun addConstraints() {
        val f = addExpression().upper(1)

        OccupationState.all.filter { it.block == this }.forEach {
            f.set(it.occupied, 1)
        }
    }
    companion object {

        // Operating blocks
        val all by lazy {
            generateSequence(operatingDates.start.atTime(operatingDay.start)) {
                it.plusMinutes(15).takeIf { it.plusMinutes(15) <= operatingDates.endInclusive.atTime(operatingDay.endInclusive) }
            }.filter { it.toLocalTime() in operatingDay }
                    .map { Block(it..it.plusMinutes(15)) }
                    .toList()
        }
    }
}


data class ScheduledClass(val id: Int,
                          val name: String,
                          val hoursLength: Double,
                          val repetitions: Int) {

    val sessions by lazy {
        Session.all.filter { it.parentClass == this }
    }

    fun addConstraints() {

        //guide 3 repetitions to be fixed on MONDAY, WEDNESDAY, FRIDAY
        if (repetitions == 3) {
            sessions.forEach { session ->
                val f = addExpression().level(session.blocksNeeded)

                session.occupationStates.asSequence()
                        .filter {
                            it.block.dateTimeRange.start.dayOfWeek ==
                                    when(session.repetitionIndex) {
                                        1 -> DayOfWeek.MONDAY
                                        2 -> DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY
                                        3 -> DayOfWeek.FRIDAY
                                        else -> throw Exception("Must be 1/2/3")
                                    }
                        }
                        .forEach {
                            f.set(it.occupied,1)
                        }
            }
        }

        //guide two repetitions to be 48 hours apart (in development)
        if (repetitions == 2) {
            val first = sessions.find { it.repetitionIndex == 1 }!!
            val second = sessions.find { it.repetitionIndex == 2 }!!
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val all by lazy { scheduledClasses }
    }
}


data class Session(val id: Int,
                   val name: String,
                   val hoursLength: Double,
                   val repetitionIndex: Int,
                   val parentClass: ScheduledClass) {

    val blocksNeeded = (hoursLength * 4).toInt()

    val occupationStates by lazy {
        OccupationState.all.asSequence().filter { it.session == this }.toList()
    }

    val start get() = occupationStates.asSequence().filter { it.occupied.value.toInt() == 1 }
            .map { it.block.dateTimeRange.start }
            .min()!!

    val end get() = occupationStates.asSequence().filter { it.occupied.value.toInt() == 1 }
            .map { it.block.dateTimeRange.endInclusive }
            .max()!!

    fun addConstraints() {

        val f1 = addExpression().level(0)
        //block out exceptions
        occupationStates.asSequence()
                .filter { os -> breaks.any { os.block.timeRange.start in it } || os.block.timeRange.start !in operatingDay }
                .forEach {
                    // b = 0, where b is occupation state
                    // this means it should never be occupied
                    f1.set(it.occupied, 1)
                }

        //sum of all boolean states for this session must equal the # blocks needed
        val f2 = addExpression().level(blocksNeeded)

        occupationStates.forEach {
            f2.set(it.occupied, 1)
        }

        //ensure all occupied blocks are consecutive
        // PROBLEM, not finding a solution and stalling

        /*
        b1, b2, b3 .. bn = binary from each group

        all binaries must sum to 1, indicating fully consecutive group exists
        b1 + b2 + b3 + .. bn = 1
         */
        val consecutiveStateConstraint = addExpression().level(1)

        (0..occupationStates.size).asSequence().map { i ->
            occupationStates.subList(i, (i + blocksNeeded).let { if (it > occupationStates.size) occupationStates.size else it })
        }.filter { it.size == blocksNeeded }
                .forEach { grp ->
                    /*
                    b = 1,0 binary for group
                    n = blocks needed
                    x1, x2, x3 .. xn = occupation states in group

                    x1 + x2 + x3 .. + xn - bn >= 0
                     */
                    val binaryForGroup = variable().binary()

                    consecutiveStateConstraint.set(binaryForGroup, 1)

                    addExpression().lower(0).apply {
                        grp.forEach {
                            set(it.occupied,1)
                        }
                        set(binaryForGroup, -1 * blocksNeeded)
                    }
                }

    }

    companion object {
        val all by lazy {
            ScheduledClass.all.asSequence().flatMap { sc ->
                (1..sc.repetitions).asSequence()
                        .map { Session(sc.id, sc.name, sc.hoursLength, it, sc) }
            }.toList()
        }
    }
}

data class OccupationState(val block: Block, val session: Session) {
    val occupied = variable().binary()

    companion object {

        val all by lazy {
            Block.all.asSequence().flatMap { b ->
                Session.all.asSequence().map { OccupationState(b,it) }
            }.toList()
        }
    }
}


fun applyConstraints() {
    Session.all.forEach { it.addConstraints() }
    ScheduledClass.all.forEach { it.addConstraints() }
    Block.all.forEach { it.addConstraints() }
}
```

** UPDATE **

I created a self-contained example that simplifies what I'm trying to do above. It seems the contiguous logic is indeed the problem, and the more "slots" the problem has the slower it performs. At 48000 variables, the contiguous logic seems to churn forever.

```
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.ExpressionsBasedModel
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.Variable
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.integer.IntegerSolver
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

// declare ojAlgo Model
val model = ExpressionsBasedModel()

// custom DSL for expression inputs, eliminate naming and adding
val funcId = AtomicInteger(0)
val variableId = AtomicInteger(0)
fun variable() = Variable(variableId.incrementAndGet().toString().let { "Variable$it" }).apply(model::addVariable)
fun addExpression() = funcId.incrementAndGet().let { "Func$it"}.let { model.addExpression(it) }


val letterCount = 9
val numberCount = 480

val minContiguousBlocks = 4
val maxContiguousBlocks = 4

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    Letter.all.forEach { it.addConstraints() }
    Number.all.forEach { it.addConstraints() }

    model.countVariables().run { println("$this variables") }

    model.options.debug(IntegerSolver::class.java)

    model.minimise().run(::println)

    Letter.all.joinToString(prefix = "\t", separator = "\t").run(::println)
    Letter.all.map { it.slotsNeeded }.joinToString(prefix = "\t", separator = "\t").run(::println)

    Number.all.forEach { n ->
        Letter.all.asSequence().map { l -> l.slots.first { it.number == n }.occupied.value.toInt() }
                .joinToString(prefix = "$n  ", separator = "\t").run { println(this) }
    }
}

class Letter(val value: String, val slotsNeeded: Int = 1) {

    val slots by lazy {
        Slot.all.filter { it.letter == this }.sortedBy { it.number.value }
    }

    fun addConstraints() {

        // Letter must be assigned once
        addExpression().level(1).apply {
            slots.forEach { set(it.occupied,  1) }
        }

        //handle recurrences
        if (slotsNeeded > 1) {
            slots.rollingBatches(slotsNeeded).forEach { batch ->

                val first = batch.first()

                addExpression().upper(0).apply {

                    batch.asSequence().flatMap { it.number.slots.asSequence() }
                            .forEach {
                                set(it.occupied, 1)
                            }

                    set(first.number.cumulativeState, -1)
                }
            }
        }

        //prevent scheduling at end of window
        // all slots must sum to 0 in region smaller than slots needed
        addExpression().level(0).apply {
            slots.takeLast(slotsNeeded - 1)
                    .forEach {
                        set(it.occupied, 1)
                    }
        }
    }

    override fun toString() = value

    companion object {

        val all = ('A'..'Z').asSequence()
                .take(letterCount)
                .map { it.toString() }
                .map { Letter(it, ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(minContiguousBlocks, maxContiguousBlocks + 1)) }
                .toList()


    }
}

class Number(val value: Int)  {

    val slots by lazy {
        Slot.all.filter { it.number == this }
    }

    // b_x
    val cumulativeState = variable().lower(0).upper(1)


    fun addConstraints() {

        // Number can only be assigned once
        addExpression().upper(1).apply {
            slots.forEach { set(it.occupied,  1) }
        }

    }

    companion object {
        val all = (1..numberCount).asSequence()
                .map { Number(it) }
                .toList()
    }

    override fun toString() = value.toString().let { if (it.length == 1) "$it " else it }
}

data class Slot(val letter: Letter, val number: Number) {

    val occupied = variable().binary()


    companion object {
        val all = Letter.all.asSequence().flatMap { letter ->
            Number.all.asSequence().map { number -> Slot(letter, number) }
        }.toList()
    }
    override fun toString() = "$letter$number: ${occupied?.value?.toInt()}"
}

fun <T> List<T>.rollingBatches(batchSize: Int) = (0..size).asSequence().map { i ->
    subList(i, (i + batchSize).let { if (it > size) size else it })
}.filter { it.size == batchSize }
```

Comment: You may debug the MIP solver using something like this:  `model.options.debug(IntegerSolver.class);` and/or you may try some other solver. The free version of CPLEX handles up to 1000 variables. https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo-extensions/tree/master/ojAlgo-cplex

Comment: Okay thanks, I will try both of these out.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that I'm already looking at commercial solvers for a _seemingly_ small problem. Granted, I realize this problem may exceed a thousand variables.

Comment: Construct a miniature instance of your problem (with all the relevant structural components) and see if ojAlgo can solve that. If it can't then try some other solver to verify that there is no problem with the model. Also note that there is a number of options that control the behaviour of the MIP solver. It is very much a possibility that the ojAlgo MIP solver actually found a solution (perhaps even "the" solution) but none of the stopping criteria are met.

Comment: I scaled the self-contained problem to 48000 "slot" binary variables, which is what I need. The contiguous logic is still causing massive slowdown for problems that grow larger than 500 binary variables. Is it possible I am pushing the limit of ojAlgo? I put the self-contained example in an update edit above.

Comment: It is definitely possible that a MIP with 48k binary variables is too much for ojAlgo.

Comment: Sorry, 4800 not 48000. I got it working after I found a way to regionalize functions to prevent overlap. Runs in 30 seconds now! Quick question though. I tried calling `model.options.iterations_suffice = 0` but it still seemed to look for alternatives even though feasible solutions were found. Am I doing it right?

Comment: I normally use time_suffice/time_abort - that works, and it's more predictable than iterations_suffice/iterations_abort. Both alternatives should work. If you can confirm a problem then please report a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I'll update this answer later with the full mathematical modeling explanation. Essentially for each 15 minute block I queried for slot groups that include that block, and declared the sum of all of them must be no more than one. This ended up being acceptably efficient as it runs in 30-60 seconds.

The code is here on GitHub, as well as below: 
https://github.com/thomasnield/optimized-scheduling-demo

```
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.integer.IntegerSolver
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalTime
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.ExpressionsBasedModel
import org.ojalgo.optimisation.Variable
import java.time.DayOfWeek
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger

// Any Monday through Friday date range will work
val operatingDates = LocalDate.of(2017,10,16)..LocalDate.of(2017,10,20)
val operatingDay = LocalTime.of(8,0)..LocalTime.of(17,0)


val breaks = listOf<ClosedRange<LocalTime>>(
        LocalTime.of(11,30)..LocalTime.of(13,0)
)


// classes
val scheduledClasses = listOf(
        ScheduledClass(id=1, name="Psych 101",hoursLength=1.0, repetitions=2),
        ScheduledClass(id=2, name="English 101", hoursLength=1.5, repetitions=3),
        ScheduledClass(id=3, name="Math 300", hoursLength=1.5, repetitions=2),
        ScheduledClass(id=4, name="Psych 300", hoursLength=3.0, repetitions=1),
        ScheduledClass(id=5, name="Calculus I", hoursLength=2.0, repetitions=2),
        ScheduledClass(id=6, name="Linear Algebra I", hoursLength=2.0, repetitions=3),
        ScheduledClass(id=7, name="Sociology 101", hoursLength=1.0, repetitions=2),
        ScheduledClass(id=8, name="Biology 101", hoursLength=1.0, repetitions=2)
)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    println("Job started at ${LocalTime.now()}")

    applyConstraints()

    model.countVariables().run { println("$this variables") }

    model.options.apply {
        //debug(IntegerSolver::class.java)
        iterations_suffice = 0
    }

    println(model.minimise())

    ScheduledClass.all.forEach {
        println("${it.name}- ${it.daysOfWeek.joinToString("/")} ${it.start.toLocalTime()}-${it.end.toLocalTime()}")
    }

    println("Job ended at ${LocalTime.now()}")

}



// declare model
val model = ExpressionsBasedModel()

val funcId = AtomicInteger(0)
val variableId = AtomicInteger(0)
fun variable() = Variable(variableId.incrementAndGet().toString().let { "Variable$it" }).apply(model::addVariable)
fun addExpression() = funcId.incrementAndGet().let { "Func$it"}.let { model.addExpression(it) }



data class Block(val dateTimeRange: ClosedRange<LocalDateTime>) {

    val timeRange = dateTimeRange.let { it.start.toLocalTime()..it.endInclusive.toLocalTime() }

    val available get() =  (breaks.all { timeRange.start !in it } && timeRange.start in operatingDay)

    //val cumulativeState = variable().apply { if (available) lower(0).upper(1) else level(0) }

    val slots by lazy {
        Slot.all.filter { it.block == this }
    }

    fun addConstraints() {
        if (available) {
            addExpression().lower(0).upper(1).apply {
                ScheduledClass.all.asSequence().flatMap { it.anchorOverlapFor(this@Block) }
                        .filter { it.block.available }
                        .forEach {
                            set(it.occupied, 1)
                        }
            }
        } else {
            ScheduledClass.all.asSequence().flatMap { it.anchorOverlapFor(this@Block) }
                    .forEach {
                        it.occupied.level(0)
                    }
        }
    }

    companion object {

        // Operating blocks
        val all by lazy {
            generateSequence(operatingDates.start.atStartOfDay()) {
                it.plusMinutes(15).takeIf { it.plusMinutes(15) <= operatingDates.endInclusive.atTime(23,59) }
            }.map { Block(it..it.plusMinutes(15)) }
             .toList()
        }

        fun applyConstraints() {
            all.forEach { it.addConstraints() }
        }
    }
}


data class ScheduledClass(val id: Int,
                          val name: String,
                          val hoursLength: Double,
                          val repetitions: Int,
                          val repetitionGapDays: Int = 2) {

    val repetitionGapSlots = repetitionGapDays * 24 * 4

    val slotsNeeded = (hoursLength * 4).toInt()

    val slots by lazy {
        Slot.all.asSequence().filter { it.session == this }.toList()
    }

    val batches by lazy {
        slots.rollingRecurrences(slotsNeeded = slotsNeeded, gapSize = repetitionGapSlots, recurrencesNeeded = repetitions)
    }

    fun anchorOverlapFor(block: Block) = batches.asSequence()
            .filter { it.flatMap { it }.any { it.block == block } }
            .map { it.first().first() }

    val start get() = slots.asSequence().filter { it.occupied.value.toInt() == 1 }.map { it.block.dateTimeRange.start }.min()!!
    val end get() = start.plusMinutes((hoursLength * 60.0).toLong())

    val daysOfWeek get() = (0..(repetitions-1)).asSequence().map { start.dayOfWeek.plus(it.toLong() * repetitionGapDays) }.sorted()

    fun addConstraints() {

        //sum of all boolean states for this session must be 1
        addExpression().level(1).apply {
            slots.forEach {
                set(it.occupied, 1)
            }
        }

        //guide Mon/Wed/Fri for three repetitions
        if (repetitions == 3) {
            addExpression().level(1).apply {
                slots.filter { it.block.dateTimeRange.start.dayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.MONDAY }
                        .forEach {
                            set(it.occupied, 1)
                        }
            }
        }

        //guide two repetitions to start on Mon, Tues, or Wed
        if (repetitions == 2) {
            addExpression().level(1).apply {
                slots.filter { it.block.dateTimeRange.start.dayOfWeek in DayOfWeek.MONDAY..DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY }.forEach {
                    set(it.occupied, 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        val all by lazy { scheduledClasses }
    }
}



data class Slot(val block: Block, val session: ScheduledClass) {
    val occupied = variable().apply { if (block.available) binary() else level(0) }

    companion object {

        val all by lazy {
            Block.all.asSequence().flatMap { b ->
                ScheduledClass.all.asSequence().map { Slot(b,it) }
            }.toList()
        }
    }
}


fun applyConstraints() {
    Block.applyConstraints()
    ScheduledClass.all.forEach { it.addConstraints() }
}

fun <T> List<T>.rollingBatches(batchSize: Int) = (0..size).asSequence().map { i ->
    subList(i, (i + batchSize).let { if (it > size) size else it })
}.filter { it.size == batchSize }

fun <T> List<T>.rollingRecurrences(slotsNeeded: Int, gapSize: Int, recurrencesNeeded: Int) =
        (0..size).asSequence().map { i ->
            (1..recurrencesNeeded).asSequence().map { (it - 1) * gapSize  }
                    .filter { it + i < size}
                    .map { r ->
                        subList(i + r, (i + r + slotsNeeded).let { if (it > size) size else it })
                    }.filter { it.size == slotsNeeded }
                    .toList()
}.filter { it.size == recurrencesNeeded }
```

Comment: There are some recent changes to ojAlgo that you may want to try. I believe some MIP:s are solved a bit faster now. Get the latest source code from GitHub and give it a try. Further you may benefit from writing a custom presolver that handles those blocks of binary variables. Not sure I understand them, but if 2 or more time slots in the same block are "on", then time slots in-between them also needs to "on" , right? Ask about on the ojalgo-user mailing list if you're interested.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks. I'll play around with it this weekend and share how it goes.